# I have a word merge doc from an access database, when I changed something, it lost the link, and I can't relink it

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Word doc that is merged with Microsoft Access Database (file format is 2007-2016). I changed something in the doc that was not part of what was merged from Access, and it lost the link. I have tried relinking it and it doesn't seem to work.

It should run the SQL command when you open the Word doc but now it won't work. When I run the debugger, it highlights the second and third row. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
MailMerge.Execute Pause:=False
Documents("Certify ONLY.docm").Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

I have tried to relink using template, Word merge from scratch, and simply undoing what I did.

Comment: So just to be sure, is the document you are trying to open a ..docm, or a .docx attached to a .dotm, or what? TBH if you have older versions of the relevant .docx/.dotm/whatever files, could be useful to go back and find out exactly how the data source was specified.